# When to use set vs let vs & to view variable value

Tags: vimrc

I get a bit confused as to when we access a variable value like this:

```
:echom &textwidth
" 120
```

And when it's done like this:

```
:let a
" a                     #4
```

And when it's done like this:

```
:set textwidth?
textwidth=120
```

What is the difference between those three ways of getting the variable value, and when should they be properly used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable named `&name` is the Vim script representation of the option `name`.

So `&textwidth` is the Vim script representation of the option `textwidth`.

See `:h :let-&`.

The `let a` just prints the value of the variable `a`. I would prefer `:echo a` here.

Addon: You also might want to read `:help internal-variables` to understand the name spaces of variables.